# RegEx: How to match on the second of 2 or more dates

Tags: regex

I am trying to return a match on only the second date where there may be multiple dates present. There is not really a consistent word directly before or after to match on. Is this possible?

Also of note, the dates could be formatted as `01-01-1001`, `01/01/1001`, or `January 01, 2001` (although the last with the month spelled is uncommon).

Below is an example of some text that I would attempt to be matching and the second date in bold is an example of what I would want it to return.

Some text fields here
And others here
Exp: 03/31/15
Page:
1
2129364
23675918 INTERNET
**05/04/14**
12:04 PM MAY
ULTIMATE
42159497 93736662
WEB
04-11-18
Taxed item
June, 14 2018

Comment: What regex did you come up yourself and what tool/language are you using?

Comment: Do you realize that the date you have in bold, i.e. **05/04/14**, matches none of the formats that you have specified, which all specify 4-digit years?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it seems to work

```
(?<=(.|\n)*?(\d{2}|January)(\s|\/|-)\d{2}(\s|\/|-)(\d{2}|\d{2})(\s|\/|-))(.|\n)*? 
(\d{2}|January)(\s|\/|-)\d{2}(\s|\/|-)(\d{2}|\d{2})(\s|\/|-)
```

This code basically searches for the pattern you are looking for, PRECEEDED by the same pattern and optionally sourounded by other symbols (newline included). 
One more advise: If you want to test regex patterns, you may want to check out [this website](https://regex101.com/).

There you can also switch between languages (I have used javascript), though the basics stay more or less the same in my opinion.

Comment: I tested here and it shows there is an error: https://regex101.com/r/Q2gDV3/1/
I'm using the PHP version of RegEx.

Comment: Hm, I see. In PHP, the term "(.|\n)*?" seems not to be allowed within a lookbehind. Question: Is the example you gave in your question how your data allways looks like? if you want the "Exp: 03/31/15" to be skipped, you could also try "(?<!Exp: )(\d{2}|January)(\s|\/|-)\d{2}(\s|\/|-)(\d{2}|\d{4})", but it will also highlight any further occurences (Except for the first one, which is ignored).

Comment: No, unfortunately the content won't be consistent - so Exp: won't be present everywhere and was only an example. Basically, I want it to look for dates and just skip the first one and match on the next. Not sure if it's even possible with RegEx using PHP.

Comment: Is RegEx capable of starting the search from the end of the string and working backwards and then finding the last date match that way?